# Prevent clipping using domain in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to prevent clipping at the top most part of my chart by increasing the domain on the `yAxis` like so:

```
mainHeight = 640;
yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([mainHeight, 0])
    .domain(d3.extent([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return (d.total)+1000;
    })]));
```

The idea is to get the max data for the yAxis and increase it by 1000.

The highest total is `14348` so with 1000 added on it creates `15348`

However the top of the chart is still being clipped off and my axis hasn't increased to prevent the clipping. Even if I increase the number by `9999999999` it still doesn't happen.

The line is generated with:

```
var totalLine = d3.svg.line()
            .interpolate('monotone')
            .x(function (d) {
                return xScale(d.date);
            })
            .y(function (d) {
                return yScale(d.total);
            });
```

[image]

Comment: Just double checking: are you sure you're not resetting `yScale.domain` after that line?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado no I'm not.

Comment: Do you have an outermost `g` element which wraps all other elements? If you do, then looks like (like my problem before) you are not setting the width and height for this `g` element

Answer (score 1):

Try throwing a `.nice()` at the end.

```
yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([mainHeight, 0])
    .domain(d3.extent([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return (d.total)+1000;
    })]))
    .nice();
```

This will try to make the axis end on nice round numbers.  You can read more here: https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Quantitative-Scales.md#linear_nice

Hope this helps.